# React Typescript: Array does not map through all items

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript

I have following Table / Array:
[image]

If I press the blue button, then all items with the same group as the record should change the Status (Gratis).
But now it just change the Value of the Record and all items above it. As an example, if I press the Button on Record No. 1 then itselft and all above (No. 0) get an change of the Status (Gratis).

Following code im using to go through the array and change the Status:

```
private _updateFreeStatus = (record: QuestionModel): void => {
        fetch('api/Test/UpdateGratisStatus', {
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
            method: 'PUT',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                'group': record.group,
                'free': record.free,
            })
        });
        this.state.question.map(item => {
            if (item.group === record.group)
            {
                item.free = !record.free;
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is `this.state.question` and `record`?

Comment: @larz this.state.question is the Array of Type QuestionModel, and record is the selected record in the table (also Model of QuestionModel)

Comment: as it is written `fetch` makes the request but you don't do anything with it. to read the response, you have to attach a `.then` handler or use `async..await`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. do not mutate the state
2. create a copy, and use `setState`

Use

```js
const updatedQuestions = this.state.question.map(item => {
  if (item.group === record.group) {
    return {
       ...item,
       free: !record.free
    }
  }
  return item;
});

this.setState({question: updatedQuestions});
```